# Why does appending a NULL into a Date column result in the value 1900-01-01 being displayed?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssis, etl

I'm using an SSIS package to import a basic text file, it has 3 date fields, and sometimes some of the date fields are empty.

The imported table shows empty fields, I suppose because they are varchar(50) datatypes. But then I need to insert those records from that table into another table, where those columns are defined as Date datatypes.

When I run the insert statement, the resulting values in the destination table all show **1900-01-01** for the date, rather than **NULL** or blank. I tried forcing the value to be null, but it didn't work:

```
CASE WHEN refresh_date IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE refresh_date END AS RefreshDate
```

How can I make a Date column just accept a blank or null value?

Comment: My guess is that you have a `NOT NULL` column with a default value of `'1900-01-01'`.

Comment: Hi Gordon...what do you mean? I have the columns in the destination table all set to allow nulls, and I haven't put anything in as their default values.

Comment: Can you script out the table as a create statement and post it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The varchar field should not be casted or converted to a date if 'empty'.  When a blank, or empty string, is casted to a date it equals '1900-01-01'. You can test this by using the following algorithm:

```
SELECT CAST('' as date)
```

Using SSIS you are better of checking if the varchar(50) field equals '', and if so setting it to NULL. Here is an example SQL query:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN importedfield = '' THEN NULL
            ELSE CAST(importedfield as date)
       END AS [NewFieldname]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a derived column transformation in the Data flow task with the following expression, the issue may be caused by empty string (not NULL values)

If the input is of type Date:

```
ISNULL([DateColumn]) ? NULL(DT_DATE) : (DT_DATE)[DateColumn]
```

If the input column is of type **string**

```
(ISNULL([DateColumn]) || [DateColumn] == "") ? NULL(DT_DATE) : (DT_DATE)[DateColumn]
```

And map this column to the destination column

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check the data type of this column and see if it accepts null value.

[image]

Comment: Should be OK, the column accepts NULLs and my SQL says

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's not a null value you're entering, but rather an empty string. You mentioned they could be 
a `VARCHAR(50)` data type. So you might need to add some more logic. Try this:

`NULLIF(LTRIM(RTRIM(refresh_date)),'')`

Comment: The column allows NULLs and my SQL says

CASE WHEN refresh_date IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE refresh_date END AS RefreshDate